# Disable mouse click to show another slide in rmarkdown slidy_presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly, ioslides

I'm wondering how to disable left mouse click to show another slide in rmarkdown slidy_presentation. If I'm trying to disable/enable some category in plotly chart, it'll skip to another slide. Is there any option how to handle it. Many thanks for your suggestions in forward.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I cant reproduce your problem...

Answer (score 5):

In my current version of slidy (rmarkdown 1.6) you can `disable/enable mouse click` advance by pressing key `'k'`, when viewing the presentation.

To change the default (on file open) behavior I had to change line 55 in 
`[R package library]/rmarkdown/rmd/slidy/Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js` to

```
mouse_click_enabled: false, // enables left click for next slide
```